# perl eval not catching errors

Tags: perl, exception, try-catch, eval

the 'eval' block catches 'die' attempts. but in the code below, it fails to catch 'uninitialized value' exception.

perl code -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package poc::template;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl;

my $log_conf = "../conf/log4perl.conf";
Log::Log4perl::init($log_conf);
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();

sub doSome {
    $logger->info('doing something');
    my $add = $ARGV[0] + 4;
}

#main
$logger->info('start');
eval { doSome(); };
if ($@) {
    $logger->info('error');
}
$logger->info('stop');
```

here is the log conf -

```
log4perl.rootLogger              = DEBUG, SCREEN
log4perl.appender.SCREEN         = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.stderr  = 0
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout  = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%M:%L] %p  %F{2} - %m%n
```

here is the script output -

```
2013/02/03 16:47:02 [main:::18] INFO  template\POCTemplate.pl - start
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in addition (+) at /POCPerl/template/POCTemplate.pl line 14.
2013/02/03 16:47:02 [poc::template::doSome:13] INFO  template\POCTemplate.pl - doing something
2013/02/03 16:47:02 [main:::23] INFO  template\POCTemplate.pl - stop
```

shouldn't this eval block catch that exception ?

Comment: Why do you think it's an exception?

Comment: yes, i treated that warning as an exception. my bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is a warning, not an exception.

You could do:

```
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';
```

to make all perl-generated warnings exceptions (in a given lexical scope).